# Magento 2 Bundle Products on the Fly

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

I would have a **large number of two types of products**. Shirts and prints. There is a one to many relationships where one shirt can have multiple prints. The prints cannot be ordered separately but are customizable (in terms of color, price, and location). I also need to track inventory and currently have them as simple products.

**Is the best way to do this in magento2 to create bundles on the fly?**

Creating bundle products seems like a lot of overhead for all the different combinations. I really want to tie one simple to many for one complete product.

My thinking is when the user adds the complete product to the cart I create the bundle (based on their selections) and add that to the cart.

Answer (score 2):

Not Sure if I understood your requirement correctly, but it seems like you can use Configurable products for your requirement.

You can create **configurable products**. The configurable products have simple associated products. So using them you will have inventory tracked. In order to change the shirt/pant image on the click of the option chosen, you will need to buy/create Image swatch extension which will be compatible with configurable products.

There are several extension available over Magento Marketplace.

If inventory is not a concern, Magento2 comes with a feature of a Visual swatch, for custom options. But that's just if inventory is not a concern of you.

Comment: I have 100 different garment types and over 1000 different prints that can be put on each garment type.  I need inventory on both garments and prints.  Is creating a configurable the best option?  It feels like a a bundle would be more appropriate since I want to package two (or more, can have 10 prints on one garment) products together to create one complete product.